# get css selector string from protractor's ElementFinder

Tags: javascript, protractor

I want to create a generic function that notifies on errors

I can't seem to find a way to get the css selector from an ElementFinder member

Here's my function:

```
static waitForElementToExist(elementFinder: ElementFinder): SeleniumPromise<any> {
    return browser.wait(until.presenceOf(elementFinder),
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL,
        MyErrors.elementNotFound(<get element selector string>));
};
```

so I can return a meaningful error like:

```
could not found the element '.class-selector'
```

can anyone point me to the right direction please? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use latest protractor, try:

```
MyErrors.elementNotFound(elementFinder.locator().toString())
```

More detail, please look [locator()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.locator) api.